# Problem with converting unix time zone in lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

I import dataset from treasuredata in a JSON format and then transform unix time column to standard time using Lubridate fuction "as_datetime".
I set tz(timezone) as GMT+7 as I am in Bangkok Thailand, and use that convert datetime in my analysis. Later, I found that it is wrong and for the correct datetime I have to input tz as "GMT-7". I dont understand why.

```
as_datetime(1565923100)
#[1] "2019-08-16 02:38:20 UTC"

as_datetime(1565923100, tz = "gmt+7")
#[1] "2019-08-15 19:38:20 gmt"

as_datetime(1565923100, tz = "gmt-7")
#[1] "2019-08-16 09:38:20 gmt"

now()
#[1] "2019-08-16 10:16:17 +07"
```

From the code, the gmt-7 gives the correct time while I think I should use the gmt+7 because Bangkok timezone is gmt+7. I check using 'now' function and got the correct time too. I dont understand the logic behind the code. Thank you for any explanation.

Comment: The correct way to specify the timezone would be `as_datetime(1565923100, tz = "Asia/Bangkok")`. `as_datetime(1565923100, tz = "gmt+7")` and `as_datetime(1565923100, tz = "gmt-7")` is incorrect way which is shown by a warning `In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'gmt+7'`

Comment: `?strptime` - "Offsets from GMT (also known as UTC) are part of the conversion
     between timezones and to/from class ‘"POSIXct"’, but cause
     difficulties as they often computed incorrectly.

     They conventionally have the ***opposite sign*** from time-zone
     specifications (see ‘Sys.timezone’): positive values are East of
     the meridian."

Comment: @RonakShah - you can specify offsets but you have to get the string right: `as_datetime(1565923100, tz = "Etc/gmt+7")`

Comment: @thelatemail I see..I didn't know that. Though I am still unclear why `as_datetime(1565923100, tz = "gmt-7")` adds 7 hours to GMT time and `as_datetime(1565923100, tz = "gmt+7")` subtracts 7 in spite of having `unknown timezone `.

Comment: @RonakShah - that is surprising - it seems to be at the level of `as.POSIXct` rather than anything in lubridate - see `as.POSIXct(1565923100, tz = "-7", origin="1970-01-01")`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers and the conversion using Asia/Bangkok is very useful. However, it really bugs me why GMT+7 and GMT-7 in as_datetime give the opposite result from what I think it should be. I use the wrong conversion in the meeting yesterday and my boss seemed really pissed of.